# What is the use case of marks?

Tags: vim, sublimetext2

Both Sublime Text 2 and VIM have a feature called **marks**. However, I've not been able to find a use case for it. It feels like everything you can do with it can also be done with other things, often even better.

So the question is: what is the use case of marks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean marking text lines as in `vim`, I use it quite a bit.

For example, if you want to quickly go look at something else, you can use `ma` to mark the current line as `a`, then go check out something else in the file, then return to where you were with a simple `'a`.

Similarly, if you want to delete an unknown number of lines between your current position and somewhere else, use `ma`, go to that "somewhere else, and just use `d'a`.

There are many more things you can do with them (such as changing text between your current position and a mark), those two are just the most common ones I use (and I use them a lot).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using it as a bookmark sounds indeed useful. About the second use case, can't that also be done by using visual mode?

Comment: @Chiel92, yes, it can, it can also do more, such as select blocks rather than just lines. But marks are available in both vim _and_ vi, just on the off-chance you don't have a modern environment. Jumplists are a bit more limited since they force a specific order of locations. Your can mark a location with (for example) `mz` that will be unaffected by any further moves. At any point after that, `'z` will take you there - you just have to remember what the `z` meant :-)

Comment: From :help marks - "Uppercase marks 'A to 'Z include the file name. You can use them to jump from file to file." I use this a lot for settings, for example I might set mS for a partial or header file where I define variables, then it's two keystrokes away.